# How to fixed the mapbox navigation puck's position and direction

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-navigation

With the default mapbox navigation following mode, the puck will move to many positions on the screen and in many direction.
How can I align it to center horizontal in **bottom** of the screen and the direction always point to **top**? Then only the map move, zoom and rotate.

I tried to override `followingPitchPropertyOverride` and `followingZoomPropertyOverride`. The puck will fixed in bottom but the direction is not always point to top (the direction is depend on the remain route).

[image]

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/migrate-to-v2/#control-pucks-position-on-screen

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the example in [mapbox-navigation-android/examples/MapboxCameraAnimationsActivity.kt](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/c53c5b119702cd7423f3179baa04cca57d16e6c4/examples/src/main/java/com/mapbox/navigation/examples/core/camera/MapboxCameraAnimationsActivity.kt).

Need to use `com.mapbox.navigation.ui.maps.camera.NavigationCamera`

```
val viewportDataSource = MapboxNavigationViewportDataSource(
            mapView.getMapboxMap()
        )
val navigationCamera = NavigationCamera(
            mapView.getMapboxMap(),
            mapView.camera,
            viewportDataSource
        )
// set following mode to navigation camera
navigationCamera.requestNavigationCameraToFollowing()
```

Comment: on the images in my question, the camera already in Following mode (not overview mode). so `requestNavigationCameraToFollowing` won't make the puck fixed on center in bottom

Comment: thanks for the link to example, it's very helpful to me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a property `maximizeViewableGeometryWhenPitchZero` in `FollowingFrameOptions`, set it to `false` will make the puck always align at bottom (instead of move to many positions in map).

```
package com.mapbox.navigation.ui.maps.camera.data
class FollowingFrameOptions internal constructor() {
    ....

    /**
     * When a produced **following frame** has pitch `0` and there are at least 2 points available for framing,
     * the puck will not be tied to the bottom edge of the [MapboxNavigationViewportDataSource.followingPadding] and instead move
     * around the centroid of the framed geometry (user location plus additional points to frame together or maneuver if route is available)
     * to maximize the view of that geometry within the [MapboxNavigationViewportDataSource.followingPadding].
     *
     * Defaults to `true`.
     */
    var maximizeViewableGeometryWhenPitchZero = true
```

use

```
viewportDataSource.options.followingFrameOptions.maximizeViewableGeometryWhenPitchZero = false
```

And, to make the puck bearing be fixed to location's bearing

```
viewportDataSource.options.followingFrameOptions.bearingSmoothing.apply {
    enabled = false
}
```

Then, the result will look like

[image]