# How to fix the puck image direction with Mapbox Maps SDK on iOS?

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm trying to build some navigation animation on my own with Mapbox Maps SDK and without the Navigation SDK.

I want to align the map bearing and the puck direction (where the arrow points to) with the route line I draw on the map. I use `FollowPuckViewportState` so that my map center can move along with the change of current location of the user.

I am able to change the map bearing by setting `viewport.options`'s `bearing`, but the puck is still pointing to where my phone is physically pointing to.

I've looked through the doc but didn't find anything that allows me to set the direction of the puck. `puckBearing` on the `puckManager` only allows `heading` or `course` but I want to set to a specific bearing value.

I'v already checkout out [How to fixed the mapbox navigation puck's position and direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245562/how-to-fixed-the-mapbox-navigation-pucks-position-and-direction) but didn't find `bearingSmoothing` equivalent in iOS SDK.

Would appreciate any help!